# How to use a MySQL case statement in a window frame to calculate running total of a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns date and sales and the objective is to use case statement to create another column that shows the cumulative sum of sales for each date.

Here's the sales table

| date | sales |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-04-01 | 50 |
| 2019-04-02 | 100 |
| 2019-04-03 | 100 |

What would be the best way to write a case statement in order to meet the requirements below?

Desired output

| date | sales | cumulative |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-04-01 | 50 | 50 |
| 2019-04-02 | 100 | 150 |
| 2019-04-03 | 100 | 250 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for a case statement here; you just need the SUM window function:

```
select date, sales, sum(sales) over (order by date, id)
from sales
```

(If date is unique, ordering by date is enough.  If it is not, it is best practice to specify additional columns to order by to produce a non-arbitrary result, such as you would get if sometimes it considered rows with the same date in one order and sometimes in another.)

When you use the sum window function with no order by clause, the default window frame is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`, causing it to sum the expression for all rows being returned.  When you specify an order by, the default frame becomes `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`, summing the expression for all rows up through the current row in the given order, producing a cumulative total.  Because this is the default, there is no need to specify it; if you do specify it, it goes after the ORDER BY in the window specification.

Comment: Another user has already given this helpful answer.

Comment: and you did it wrong, Tim :)

Comment: There is no `case` statement in SQL, it is case expression.

Comment: Thanks @ysth. However, the requirement is for me to use a case statement. Is that possible?

Comment: Yeah case expression

Comment: as Tim says, there is no case statement in mysql.  There is a case expression, but it is of no use here.  Or perhaps you mean a window frame?  Please provide additional information about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: you'd use a case expression if you wanted to do something like have separate columns with cumulative sales for weekdays and weekends.

Comment: yes @ysth window frame

Comment: your edit to your question title still shows confusion.  you use the sum window function to get a cumulative total.  window functions operate over a set of the rows being returned; which rows those are determined by the window frame.  there's still no reason for a case expression that you have shown here.

Comment: Got the answer now. Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `CASE` *expression*, but rather just use `SUM()` as a window function:

```sql
SELECT date, sales, SUM(sales) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS cumulative
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. However, the requirement is to use a case statement. Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you think you need a `CASE` expression here?

Comment: I got the answer now from the shared query above. Thanks to both of you :)